# Evaluation for math expression gone wrong : python

Tags: python, math, iterator, iteration

I adopted a function to evaluate a list of strings consisting of numbers and math expressions, but I could not get the expected result.
For example : 5+2-3+2 = 6

Basically, the function starts by initializing result the value of the first numeric input (Inp). It then applies the operations, left to right, to the current result and so on, until it gets the final result.
Below is the script.

```
Inp = ["5","+","2","-","3","+","2"]

result = Inp [0]
for i in range (1, len(Inp), 2):
    op = Inp [i]
    nextValue = Inp [i + 1]
if op == '+':
    result += nextValue
elif op == '-':
    result -= nextValue
return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issue in your code.

1) You are taking the first element of `Inp` as `result`. But `Inp[0]` is basically a string. So convert it to integer before assigning.

2) The `if` and `else` should be inside the `for` loop. Indentation is not correct.

3) Same problem like 1 in case of statement inside `if` and `else`

4) There are no function (as per your given code). No need to return. If it is indeed a function and this is a minimal version, then it is ok.

Then the correct code will be -

```
Inp = ["5","+","2","-","3","+","2"]

result = int(Inp [0])
for i in range (1, len(Inp), 2):
    op = Inp [i]
    nextValue = Inp [i + 1]
    if op == '+':
        result += int(nextValue)
    elif op == '-':
        result -= int(nextValue)

print result
```

Also inside `if` and `else` you may want to check if `nextValue` is indeed a number

There are other ways to do what you want. I just pointed out the errors and change your code to a functional one.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose an easy way to is to get the first operand out of the way, then loop through the list by twos. Don't forget, you have to convert the values from strings to integers, otherwise 5+2 will be 52 and not 7:

```
data = ["5","+","2","-","3","+","2"]
result = int(data[0])

for op, n in zip(data[1:][::2], data[1:][1::2]):
   if op == '+':
     result += int(n)
   if op == '-':
     result -= int(n)

print(result)
```

The core idea is the for loop. It works by using slicing:

- `data[1:]` this is your initial list, minus the first element (which we already used)
- `[::2]` means "every other element"
- `[1::2]` means "every other element, but skip the first one"

We `zip()` the two lists to get a pair of operator and operands, like this:

```
>>> for a in zip(data[1:][::2],data[1:][1::2]):
...   print(a)
...
('+', '2')
('-', '3')
('+', '2')
```

This is a safe way to loop through the list, because we don't have to worry about looping beyond the end of the list.

The rest of the logic is the same as yours, except you forgot to convert the values to integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Inp = ["5","+","2","-","3","+","2"]
def f(Inp):
 result = int(Inp [0])
 for i in range (1, len(Inp), 2):
    op = Inp [i]
    nextValue = int(Inp [i + 1])
    if op == '+':
        result += nextValue
    elif op == '-':
        result -= nextValue
 return result

print(f(Inp))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems with this code: first you have some issues with indentation. Everything inside the for loop should be indented one space.
Second, the return statement does not work unless you are inside of a function. There is no function definition here, so the best you can do is print it. Last, you are using numbers in quotes, like "5" which turns 5 into a string rather than treating it as a number. Here is a version of this which works:

```
Inp = [5,"+",2,"-",3,"+",2]

result = Inp [0]
for i in range (1, len(Inp), 2):
    op = Inp [i]
    nextValue = Inp [i + 1]
    if op == '+':
        result += nextValue
    elif op == '-':
        result -= nextValue

print(result)
```